# Laravel self based polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables:

- `categories`
- `admins`
- `users`

Category can create users and admins. In `categories` table I have `morphs` field:

`$table->nullableMorphs('userable');`

And relations in `Category` model:

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne(self::class, 'userable');
}
```

But when I tried do like this:

```
$category = Category::first();
$user = User::first();

$category->user()->save($user);
```

Get error with message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userable_id' in 'field list'
> (SQL: update `users` set `userable_id` = 1, `userable_type` =
> App\Models\Category, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-04-27 12:13:22 where
> `id` = 1)'

How I can correctly create self morph relationship in laravel?

Comment: Can you show us your migration?

Comment: Categories table migration? @SpaceDogCS

Comment: Oh, forget, now I understood what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

So I think that what you should be doing is adding to the User model and the Admin model the relation user you've added to the category, those models that have this relationship can be morphed into the category

```
class User {
    ...

    public function user() {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'userable');
    }

    ...
}


class Admin {
    ...

    public function user() {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'userable');
    }

    ...
}
```

so you can do your logic this way

```
$category = Category::first();
$user = User::first();

$user->user()->save($category);
```

and it will update you category record with userable_type beeing App\Models\User and userable_id beeing 1 or whatever the user id is

| id | name | userable_type | userable_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category Test | App\Models\User | 1 |

to make things easier you can create a trait and add that relationship to the trait

```
trait IsUserable {

    public function user() {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'userable');
    }

}
```

and instead of adding the relationship to User and Admin model, you just use the trait instead

```
class User {
    use IsUserable;
}


class Admin {
    use IsUserable;
}
```